# Can not initialize UI with bound object in QML/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I put a `RangeSlider` which is from `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` into a Component. I've bound its `min.value` to my model object, which is a subclass of `QObject` and has been exposed to QML context.

I can access it from QML using the name: "settings". The control is supposed to read settings in the Loader's `onLoaded:{...}` to initialize itself. I have a `Binding`-Object outside of the `Loader` to write back any changes of the `min.value`. 
But the control always set the settings' properties first, so I can not initialize it with settings's perperties.

```
Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: ctrl
    onLoaded: {
         loader.item.min = settings.min
    } 
}
Binding {
    target: settings
    property: "min"
    value: loader.item.min.value
}
Component {
    id: ctrl
    Item {
        property alias min: slider.first
        RangeSlider {
            id: slider
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I want to assign `loader.item.min.value` (i.e. `slider.first.value`) the value of settings.min, but before this assignment happens, the settings.min is changed to `slider.first.value`. After the user set a new value, I want the `settings.min` to be set to `slider.first.value`.

Is there anybody know how to implement this correctly?

Comment: I will try to use setSource method of Loader : 
object setSource(url source, object properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`when`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html#when-prop)-property of the the `Binding`-Object to deactivate the binding, until you have set the inital value. Set it initally to `false`, and change it to `true` in the first line of your `onLoaded`-handler

Also very interesting is the [`delayed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html#delayed-prop)-property. I can't guarantee you that this will work, but it might be an elegant solution. I have not tried it out yet.